# defining field types in R arcgisbinding

Tags: r, arcgis, r-sf

I am using `arc.write()` in the R `arcgisbinding` package to write an `sf` object to a feature class in a file geodatabase.

How do I define the field types of the resulting feature class?

For example, I have a field in R which is a `character` field, eg :

```
"2018-11-10"
```

When I write this file to a feature class, this field gets interpreted as a `double` field, but I want this field to be interpreted as a `text` field.

```
fgdb_path <- file.path("path")

arc.write(file.path(fgdb_path, "layer"), data=sf_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge) of the package is seems that Date have added on December 2015 ([see commit](https://github.com/R-ArcGIS/r-bridge/commit/d753d0fa3883e6c9bb5ad60f924b1f3781ad27ed)).

Thus to convert directly to date into ArcGIS your column should be transform as POSIXct:

```
as.POSIXct("2018-11-10", format = "%F")
```

The format `%F` is explained in the help of `strftime()` and lets you decompose the way your date is written. Because you're using the ISO 8601 date format the format is defined as `%F`.

You can change your column type then try to write the file to a feature class and telle how it worked.